# When to use f:= x vs f[x_]:= x?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, symbolic

I have many compound functions, using the same variables. I can define them like this:

```
f[x_,y_]:= ...
g[x_,y_]:= ...
h[x_,y_]:= f[x,y] + g[x,y]
```

or like

```
f:= ...
g:= ...
h:=f+g

h/.{x-> smth ,y->smth}
```

Is there a reason to use on over another?

Comment: With f[x_,,y_]:=... you can use any arguments you like, even expressions. With f=... you are stuck to the arguments you use in the definition.

Comment: I would use `f[x_]:=` to define something I think of as a function and `f=` (`=` rather than `:=` generally) when I think of `f` as an expression (and I'd be unlikely to call it `f` but give it a meaningful name like `energy`.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `:=` and `=`? Are you using `:=` instead of `=` in your `f := ...` example on purpose?

Comment: @Szabolcs I am aware of the difference, I don't want it to be evaluated right away because if I change f[x_,y_], then h with delayed evaluation will take that change into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the comments, `f[x_, y_] := ...` when `f` is to be used like a function and `f = ...` when it is an (algebraic) expression, here are a couple of situations where I take one approach one and not the other.

When programming (e.g., writing a procedure that may be used and reused), I use functions (`f[x_, y_] :=...`) and I usually make all the variables and parameters arguments. If doing a sequence of calculations (either a one-off or inside a function), I use variables (`f =...`).

As the OP points out, Mathematica can treat functions as expressions and expressions as functions with relatively little inconvenience, with perhaps one exception: Arguments to functions (`x_` etc.) are localized and protected from external, global values. One can use `Block[]` to localize variables in calculations, but that borders on being inconvenient. In programming, it is often more than inconvenient and can cause problems that cannot be solved. (`Module[]` does not really work if your sequence of calculations extends across more than one cell, but of course it's the right way to localize variables in a function.)

On `f := expr` versus `f = expr`, the difference is when things are evaluated. In the first, `expr` is not evaluated when `f` is set; it is evaluated every time `f` is evaluated.  In the second, `expr` is evaluated before `f` is set to its value.  You can play with the following and change `:=` to `=` and predict when `f` will give the same value for `RandomReal[]` and when it changes randomly.

```
Clear[x, y]
x = 1;
f := {x, y, RandomReal[]};
?f
y = 1;
f
f
x = y = 2;
f
```